# Is university teaching better than high school teaching experience in applying for teaching-funded PhDs?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, teaching, mathematics, funding

When applying for graduate assistantships or part-time teaching for grad school scholarships, is university teaching necessarily better than highschool teaching experience? if so, by how much?

Possibly relevant details:

1. I am [graduating soon](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29343/if-co-instructors-gave-different-syllabi-with-different-grading-schemes-is-this) with a master's degree from a third world university.
2. My plan is to get a PhD but am considering getting teaching experience to boost my chance's of getting in.
3. I am considering teaching at my university (or another university in my country) for a year or so.
4. However, I have something like a dual citizenship in a first world country in the sense that I permitted to work there in addition to an established residence (my mom and sister live there while my dad and brother live with me).
5. Said FWC is where I would like to get my PhD.
6. My parents suggested I teach at my sister's highschool (or some highschool in said FWC since I will unlikely get into one of the universities there).
7. I am fine with either in terms of job requirements (e.g. highschool has more requirements and students tend to snooze off more), but the pay is alarmingly different by a factor of 5.

Another difference is that if I teach in my university long enough, I might be able to teach or assist in teaching advanced stuff like probability, linear algebra, calculus III or financial maths. There's also a tutorial center nearby and there are occasional students who need tutorials in probability, statistics and linear algebra.

Comment: In the US (and probably in Europe too, though I don't have direct experience with things overseas), there is no expectation that candidates for teaching assistantships have *any* teaching experience.  And at least at my institution having teaching experience would not really have any effect on your chance of being admitted.

Comment: Although what @AndyPutman said is certainly correct, so far as I know in the U.S., having _some_ experience with the ambient culture, and _some_ teaching experience in that culture, can be a slight plus, especially if command of spoken English is potentially an issue.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to include in what field you want to pursue a PhD. If, for instance, you think about a PhD in education (possibly in the teaching of mathematics) it could be an advantage to teach at a High School. I don't know how the regulations are in other countries, but in the Netherlands you cannot just teach at a high school without education in high school teaching (after university, a one year master course)

Comment: @AndyPutman I was wondering because I was thinking of teaching while applying as I would start applying after the heavy portions of my master's. Thanks.

Comment: @MaartenvanWesel Not for what I was going but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is an option definitely university teaching is more valuable as it is at the same level as the teaching you will experience while doing your degree. However, you should consider that PhD is a research-based degree and teaching obligation is not primary concern. So you might get the position without having any teaching experience and finally get your PhD being a year or so younger.

Comment: I was wondering because I was thinking of teaching while applying as I would start applying after the heavy portions of my master's. Thanks Kid.